# cardano-cli not showing utxo but Testnet Blockchain Explorer does

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-node, plutus-playground

I have requested funds via Faucet, twice in fact because the first one I thought the request didn't go through but when I run:

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat 01.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

I don't get the utxo output but only get a blank line for the hash and transactions. However when I look up the address in the Cardano Blockchain Explorer Testnet I can in fact verify I have 2000 ADA's in that address.

I wonder why this is or what I might have missed doing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your local cardano-node fully updated?

Comment: Not sure. I've been running it but how do I know when the node is fully updated?

Comment: With : cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063 . 
As result you should get: "syncProgress": "100.00"

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm allowing the node to fully sync with the blockchain which incidentally took quite a bit of time fixed the issue. Once the sync was fully established the cardano-cli did output the relevant utxo info.